# Calculate coordinates of third point on a triangle

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

I have two points coordinates, A (x,y) and B (x,y) and a distance L, that distance is AC and BC, I don't have the distance for AB, and I have to find the coordinates for the point C

Comment: if you have coordinates for A and B, you ovbiously have distance AB. Also, you mention AC=BC = L. Use formula a/sinA=b/SinB=c/sinC to find angles and then you can have coordinates for C. Or did I get the question wrong?

Answer (score 0):

1) From $A(x_A, y_A)$ and $B(x_B, y_B)$, find $x_M$ and $y_M$, where M is the midpoint of AB.

[image]

2) Find $m_{AB}$, the slope of AB. Hence, find $m_{MC}$, the slope of the line perpendicular to AB.

3) Use point-slope form to setup the equation of MC.

4) Set up the equation of the circle (centered at $A(x_A, y_A)$, radius = L).

5) The x-roots obtained by solving the above two equations are $x_{C}$ and $x_{C’}$. They happen to be the x-coordinates of $C$ and $C’$.